# How can we make sure we are connected to the provider?

Tags: web3js

I'm looking to connect to a WebSocket Provider, and intermittently I'll get  an error saying:

```
Error: connection not open
[0]     at WebsocketProvider.send
```

Does a WebSocket connection contain callback data that I can reference so that I can begin calling functions *AFTER* my provider has been set?

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two ways to detect and retrieve the status of a *Websocket Provider* connection. One could be through *Web3 Provider* events and the other could be by calling the `isListening` *API* function.

Consider the following code example `websocket.js`, written in *JavaScript* using the `web3` library:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const address = "wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws";
const web3 = new Web3(address);
const provider = web3.currentProvider;
provider.on("connect", function () {
    console.log("Websocket Provider connection established!");
});
web3.eth.net.isListening(function(error, result) {
    if(error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        console.log("Websocket Provider connection is listening. Status: " + result);                                                                                       
    }
});
```

Running with `yarn add web3 && node websocket.js`, considering the endpoint is available and connectivity status is positive, results in:
Websocket Provider connection established!
Websocket Provider connection is listening. Status: true

More detailed error handling could be done by registering to other events such as `"error"` and `"end"` via additional `provider.on` statements.

Hope that helps you :)

Stay super!

/Javi